# How does a port listening works?

Tags: performance, port, labview

I was wondering how a port listening works. I can only image a loop which always looks for "something" new. But that looks very inefficient to me

If it helps: My concrete problem is that I have two computers and a server. The first computer creates data and stores it on the server. My program - I want to program on the second computer - now should always read the new file on the server when it is been created. The data creating software is written in LabVIEW and my program is a C++/Qt application. My idea is to listen at a port for the file or just the information to look at the server folder. (There it should be stored anyway)

As an additional question: Should I dig deeper in port listening/understanding or is it comparable efficient to check the server folder for new files every *n* milliseconds?

Comment: This is a bit off-topic for SO, try asking at [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

1) You could either use `inotify` ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify)) on the server probably (but maybe on your second PC if the filesystem is shared via Samba) to be informed when the file changes and then start processing it. This works on Linux, but you didn't mention your OS/platform.

2) You could use a socket or port to notify your "second" computer that there is new data on the server to process. If you choose this approach, you could test it out at the command line using `netcat`, or `nc` as it is sometimes called. It is available for Windows and is installed on pretty much all Linux and OSX distributions. You could simply leave your second computer waiting on a read from a socket that passes it the filename. So your second computer would do:

```
while :
do
   file=$(netcat -l 2000)
   echo New file available $file
done
```

And your server, or first computer would do this when there is a new file:

```
echo filename | netcat <ip address of second computer> 2000
```

I chose the port=2000 because ports under 1024 need special privileges, but you can choose any port you like.

Waiting on a port/socket is blocking and doesn't use much CPU by the way.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not linux but windows. Nevertheless the second ansatz works thanks. I still don't know how a port listening works but at least I know that there is no loop (checking every ms for something new).